# how to declare a template friend function to a variadic class

Tags: c++, c++14

How do you declare a template function a friend of a variadic class, both inside and outside the class declaration?

For example, this is how I'd think you'd write it inside the class declaration, but I'm getting an undefined reference error.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

namespace ns
{
    template<class...>
    class Example;

    template<class A, class... Bs>
    std::vector<A>& get(Example<Bs...>& pExample);

    template<class... As>
    class Example
    {
    private:
        std::tuple<std::vector<As>...> mVectors;

    public:
        explicit Example(std::size_t pCapacity)
                : mVectors(std::vector<As>(pCapacity)...)
        {}

        template<class B> //Error: undefined reference to `std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >& ns::get<int, int, float>(ns::Example<int, float>&)
        friend std::vector<B>& get(Example<As...>& pExample)
        {
            return std::get<std::vector<B>>(pExample.mVectors);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: The code you show [compiles for me](http://rextester.com/RPTTEM53254). To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie in the code you haven't shown. Prepare [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It might compile because the function is never used. Besides the main function which is `ns::Example<int, float> example(100); std::vector<int>& ref = ns::get<int>(example);` this is the only code I wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Friend functions do *not inherit* the template parameter.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

namespace ns
{
    template<class... As>
    class Example;

    template<class B, class... As>
    std::vector<B>& get(Example<As...>& pExample);

    template<class... As>
    class Example
    {
    private:
        std::tuple<std::vector<As>...> mVectors;

    public:
        explicit Example(std::size_t pCapacity)
            : mVectors(std::vector<As>(pCapacity)...)
        {}

        template<class B, class... Cs> // <----
        friend std::vector<B>& get(Example<Cs...>& pExample)
        {
            return std::get<std::vector<B>>(pExample.mVectors);
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    ns::Example<int,short,char> e(10);
    auto v = ns::get<int>(e);
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://ideone.com/7y058Z)</kbd>